# Extend automatically last column in a View - Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a view that contains 5 columns. When the application is running, after the 5th ( last column ) there is a big space whici goes at the end of the view.

I want the last column of the view to be extended automatically and to go as far as the view is. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to check "Extend last column to window width" on the Style tab of View properties:
[image]